# AppScript (Apple Script) library in Python. Getting ALL desktops, both active and inactive

Tags: python, python-2.7, applescript, sourceforge-appscript

Today I created a program that gets the current most popular movies from Themoviedb.org's API, chooses one at random, and sets my desktop image to a HD backdrop of the chosen movie. I set up a cron job to have it run every hour and it works beautifully ([screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRNFX.jpg)).

The issue I'm having is that only the desktop that is currently active (plus future desktops) are changed. None of the other already opened desktops are changed (they still have the previous desktop image).
How do I have both active and inactive desktops change?

```
from tmdb3 import set_key, set_cache, Movie
from appscript import *
import random, time, urllib, os

set_key('API_KEY_REMOVED_FOR_POST')

set_cache(filename='movies.cache')


def setDesktop(title, movieUrl):
    # Save backdrop image
    test = urllib.urlretrieve(movieUrl, "backdrops/" + title + ".jpg")
    # Get Desktops
    se = app('System Events')

    desktops = se.desktops.display_name.get()

    for d in desktops:
        desk = se.desktops[its.display_name == d]
        desk.picture.set(mactypes.File("backdrops/" + title + ".jpg"))


def removeBackdrops():
    fileList = os.listdir('backdrops')

    for file in fileList:
        os.remove('backdrops/' + file)

def main(): 
    # Delete backdrop
    removeBackdrops()

    # Get most popular movies
    popularMovies = Movie.mostpopular()

    # Limit results to 45 items.
    limit = 45

    # Init movie list
    movieList = []

    # Append movies to list
    for x in range(0, limit):
        movieList.append(popularMovies[x])

    movie = random.choice(movieList)

    # Set desktop
    setDesktop(movie.title, movie.backdrop.geturl())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Lines 16 and 18 seem to only get the physical displays as opposed to the different desktops.

Using OSX Yosemite and Python 2.7.6.

I'd appreciate any help! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it programmatically but here's a thought. You know you can set the desktop image by pointing at folder of images and have it set the desktop from a random image in that folder. You can even set the time for how often it changes the desktop image.

Now what if you did that for all of your desktops. You point them to a folder with only 1 image. Then when you get the movie image, instead of changing the desktop programmatically, you just replace the image in the folder with the movie image. Then the next time the desktops are set to automatically change they will of course choose your movie image.

I didn't try this but it would probably work and it may suffice for your needs.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  One reason I have the files be deleted and named after the movie title is because when the image was being replaced with the same name, the OS didn't recognize that the image has changed.  Even if I delete the image, the wallpaper stays the same.  Something tells me that the system makes a copy elsewhere to use for the desktop but I can be wrong.